# How to open lookup field record in force record view tag?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I am using force record view tag `<force:recordView recordId="{!v.agreementId}"/>` to view all the fields of a record. For the lookup fields related to selected record, name is clickable but lookup record is not opening. Please tell me if it is possible to open the lookup record.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this inside of the SF lightning Exp? Click the link fires a 'force:navigateToSObject' event. So this will not work in Visualforce or Apps. You can handle it yourself in that case. Something like:

in your cmp:

```
<aura:handler event="force:navigateToSObject" action="{!c.navigateToRecord}"/>
```

and your controller:

```
,
navigateToRecord: function(cmp, evt){
    window.location = '/' + evt.getParam('recordId');
}
```